# How to combine multiple rows in Postgres using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Using nodeJS how would I be able to join multiple rows into one string value in json output? Right now it output multiple rows but I would like to combine values into one row.

```
      GTIN     |       Name       |       TypeCode      |     Value
--------+----------------+------------------+------------------------
26001087006846 |   Product Name   |        Name1        |       1
26001087006846 |   Product Name   |        Name2        |       2
26001087006846 |   Product Name   |        Name3        |       3
26001087006846 |   Product Name   |        Name4        |       4
```

Desired Outcome

```
[{"GTIN":"26001087006846","Name":"Product Name","Name1":"1","Name2":"2","Name3":"3","Name4":"4"}]
```

Query statment

```
 pool.query(
  'SELECT table_name."GTIN" FROM table_name WHERE table_name."GTIN" = $1'
    , [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
```

Comment: you could generate the json object from postgres directly: `select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
    from (
      select * from table_name
    ) t`

Comment: Depending on your version of PostgreSQL, `json_agg` could come in handy there, too.